What are matrices with the property $A^n=A$ where $n>2$ called.
I'm trying to finding out more information about matrices which have the following that $A^n=A$, where $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix and $n>2$. I know that if $A^2=A$ then $A$ is an idempotent matrix, but I'm specifically looking for more information about $2\times2$ matrices which have this property for a value of $n$ where $n>2$.
For example if
$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ then $A^3=A$.
Or if
$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} -3 & -2\\ 5 & 3 \end{array}\right)$ then $A^5=A$.

Does this answer your question? Generalisation of idempotent matrices to higher powers In particular, the terminology of "periodic matrix" is also used by MathWorld.
